# WordPress is removing trailing slash

Tags: htaccess, domain

Unfortunately, it seems I have a misconfiguration in my wordpress instance. WordPress seems to remove the trailing slash. This only happens when the domain is accessed via www.

When I open http://schwelme.de/merkzettel/, everything seems to work. However, when I open http://www.schwelme.de/merkzettel/, the trailing slash is removed.

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.schwelme.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.schwelme.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The root domain is set to https://www.schwelme.de. The permalink structure is set to https://schwelme.de/%postname%/.

Edit: The problem seems to occur only when I call the domain via http. If I call it encrypted, there is no problem.

Comment: How are you doing the http -> https redirect? [Does this answer help?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103882/wordpress-http-to-https-without-trailing-slash-results-in-double-redirect)

Comment: About the .htaccess file. I just installed Really Simple SSL again y. Unfortunately, this also brings no success.

Comment: To further debug this, I would suggest you do the http -> https in a better controlled manner (e.g. code in .htaccess that you can influence) rather than relying on plugins. Once this is done and the problem persists, it can be debugged much better.

Comment: You should state in your question exactly what it is redirecting to. Having just had a look at the URL on your site, it's not "removing the trailing slash". It's removing the slash at the _start_ of the URL-path. ie. immediately after the hostname. eg. `https://www.example.demerkzettel/`. The error would seem to be in the HTTP to HTTPS redirect. This appears to be triggered by Apache, not WordPress (looking at the response headers). So, as @kero already asked, where is this being triggered? It's not in the `.htaccess` file you've posted. Is something set in your webhosting control panel?